# PdfSharp/MigraDoc - how to shade part of a paragraph

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

Is there a way to apply shading to part (for example, just a word) of a `Paragraph` in PdfSharp/MigraDoc? I tried adding a `Style` with the shading to the `Document` and then passing the style name to the `AddFormattedText` method but it only takes the font information from the style.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using PdfSharp/MigraDoc from few weeks and before answer precisely to your question I've read the source code of it, freely disponible.

The short answer is: **IS NOT POSSIBLE**

The **long** answer is:
The only part on Style considered by  `AddFormattedText(string text, string style)` is the Character part. Then the `Shading`, that is a part of `ParagraphFormat`, cannot be applied, and the renderized, by PdfSharp/MigraDoc.

The coded answer is:

```
   public FormattedText AddFormattedText(string text, string style)
    {
      FormattedText formattedText = AddFormattedText(text);
      formattedText.Style = style;
      return formattedText;
    }



 internal class FormattedTextRenderer : RendererBase
   ...
 /// <summary>
    /// Renders the style if it is a character style and the font of the formatted text.
    /// </summary>
    void RenderStyleAndFont()
    {
      bool hasCharacterStyle = false;
      if (!this.formattedText.IsNull("Style"))
      {
        Style style = this.formattedText.Document.Styles[this.formattedText.Style];
        if (style != null && style.Type == StyleType.Character)
          hasCharacterStyle = true;
      }
      object font = GetValueAsIntended("Font");
      if (font != null)
      {
        if (hasCharacterStyle)
          this.rtfWriter.WriteControlWithStar("cs", this.docRenderer.GetStyleIndex(this.formattedText.Style));

        RendererFactory.CreateRenderer(this.formattedText.Font, this.docRenderer).Render();
      }
    }
```

I hope this can help you.
Davide.

Answer (score 1):

You can try loading your style to the Paragraph like this:

```
paragraph = section.AddParagraph();    
paragraph.Style = "StyleName";
```

Personally I didn't use the shading feature, but that's the way I load my styles and it works ok.

Comment: That adds a new paragraph though. I'm looking for a way to change the shading for a section of a paragraph not the whole paragraph itself.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? You could just use a workaround and try creating a new paragraph containing the single word or just "your section", and then style the new paragraph acordingly.